# Select an array from a multidimensional array

Tags: python, list

In the following array, I want select a sub-array from array `a` when an id is known

```
a=[['id123','ddf',1],['id456','ddf',1],['id789','ddf',1]]
```

I know the id i.e, id456, based on this how can I select the values `['id456','ddf',1]` from `a` without using any loop.

Comment: `without using any loop`. Is this homework?

Comment: definitively not an homework..

Comment: What do you mean by no loop? As in no normal for loop? Are generator expressions like mine allowed?

Comment: this is a simple one ;) , just call it like you would any other list. `a[0]` should do the trick :)

Comment: If the list is sorted it should be possible to fetch a value in O(log n) time, but a loop of some sort (explicitly with a for loop or implicitly via more nuanced syntax) would still be required.  You need a dictionary, or some other kind of mapping data structure, to do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a = [['id123','ddf',1],['id456','ddf',1],['id789','ddf',1]]
>>> next(x for x in a if x[0] == 'id456')
['id456', 'ddf', 1]
```

I would however, recommend the use of a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work...

```
filter(lambda x:x[0]=='id456',a)[0]
```

But in this case, wouldn't a dictionary be a better data structure?

Comment: That would still go through the entire list before it completes. And imo, a dictionary as you stated would be a better data structure to use.

Comment: @ChristianWitts This could work efficiently in Python 3 using `next` instead of `[0]` but as it is I agree that is inefficient and the use of lambda makes it ugly when compared to a generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary structure would work a lot better.

```
b = {'id123': ['ddf', 1], 'id456': ['dff', 1], 'id789': ['ddf', 1]}
print b['id123']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is sorted, you can use the `bisect` module:

```
>>> i = bisect.bisect_left(a, ['id456'])
>>> if i < len(a) and a[i][0]=='id456':
...     print a[i]
...
['id456', 'ddf', 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where()` to do that:

```
a = numpy.array(a)

row = numpy.where(a == 'id456')[0]

sub_array = a[row,:]
```

This will check for elements with the desired id and give back their indexes. You can use these indexes to take slices from the original array, as the example shows.

This code will only work if there is a single row for the given ID, but it can be adapted.

Hope this helps.